# How to create a generic field like version in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am creating a restful service from Grails and would like to add a user field on every table which on insert or on update automatically changed to the corresponding user making the change.

Is there any way to create a variable like `version` or `dateCreated` which are automatically bound to each domain where defined and added automatically updated on creation or update?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Define an abstract domain class, put your common fields on it (on `src/groovy`)
**2.** Extend it by each domain object that needs the common fields

So your abstract domain class will look like this (also note how the `updateByUser` and `createdByUser` are automatically determined):

```
abstract class AbstractDomain  {

    transient securityService

    User createdByUser;
    User updatedByUser;

    def beforeInsert() {

        if(null != securityService) {

            User currentUser = securityService.getCurrentUser()

            if(null != currentUser){
                this.createdByUser = currentUser
            }
        }
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {

        if(null != securityService) {

            User currentUser = securityService.getCurrentUser()

            if(null != currentUser){
                this.updatedByUser = currentUser
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `transient securityService` should be `def springSecurityService; static transients = ['springSecurityService]`, right?

Comment: yea you are right, but  it works for this one, when I add another transient field(String,date...) I have to use `static transients = ['springSecurityService]` because `transient fieldType fieldName` works sometimes but sometimes it does not.